# Find all non co-linear points

Tags: graphics, geometry, computer-science, computational-geometry, convex-hull

Given a set of points in the 2-D Plane, is it possible to find a set of all possible non co-linear points in the 2-D plane?
Time Complexity doesn't matter at present just that the solution be correct.

Comment: Don't you mean non-collinear point *triples* ?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for might need clarification. Any two points are collinear to each other, since a line connects them. To make this question answerable, it seems I must interpret what you're asking to mean this: that if any number of points greater than or equal to three are all collinear with each other, our set of non-collinear points can contain only one of the collinear points.

Given this, we can do the following:

1. for each pair of points, calculate the slope between them as (y - y') / (x - x'). If x = x', simply note that slope as V.
2. next, for each pair of points and slope, check all the other pairs of points involving either of the points in the pair and see whether the corresponding slope is the same as the one being checked. Take all the points so determined and add them to a collection and add this collection to a collection.
3. Once you have finished, you will have a collection of collections, and all the points in each collection in your collection will consist of points which are all collinear to each other.

Now the problem is the following: Find the largest number of points that can be chosen so that no two points exist in two of the collections. If you picked two points that were in one of the collections, you'd have picked two points that were collinear together with at least one other point.

At this point, we can simply try all 2^n subsets of n points and check each one to see if it is acceptable (in that the intersection of the subset and any collection has size at most one).

Example:

```
p = (1, 1), q = (2, 2), r = (3, 3), s = (2, 3)

m = [ - 1 1 2]
    [ 1 - 1 V]
    [ 1 1 - 0]
    [ 2 V 0 -]

(p, q): r yes, s no; collection (p, q, r)
(p, r): q yes, s no; collection (p, q, r)
(p, s): q no, r no; no collection
(q, p): r yes, s no; collection (p, q, r)
(q, r): p yes, s no; collection (p, q, r)
(q, s): p no, r no; no collection
(r, p): q yes, s no; collection (p, q, r)
(r, q): p yes, s no; collection (p, q, r)
(r, s): p no, q no; no collection
(s, p): q no, r no; no collection
(s, q): p no, r no; no collection
(s, r): p no, q no; no collection

Try candidate (p, q, r, s): intersection with (p, q, r) has size > 1, reject
Try candidate (p, q, r): intersection with (p, q, r) has size > 1, reject
Try candidate (p, q, s): intersection with (p, q, r) has size > 1, reject
…
Try candidate (p, s): intersection with (p, q, r) has size = 1, accept
```

This is clearly exponential in time and space but this will solve the problem.